# Compiling with MinGW gcc Makes windows defender suspect of virus

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, windows-defender

This never happened to me before, but today I compiled a program with MinGW gcc and windows defender thought that the executable was a torjan, more specifically Win32/Fuerboos.C!cl

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?name=Trojan%3aWin32%2fFuerboos.C!cl&threatid=2147723654

I had previously compiled programs with this installation of gcc, but today suddenly windows defender tarted acting on the executables, is my pc infected? Did this ever happened to any one?

Comment: This happens constantly, has been happening forever.

Comment: I didn't know it was usual, but thank you for the information! :)

Comment: I noticed this today, and I experienced the same bullshit messages from the windows antivirus. I was in fact was quite scared to have let run a compromised payload from osdn.net. Does anyone know an efficient way to report this problem to Microsoft? This cleary doesn't ever get fixed...

Comment: I just got bitten by this too. For clarity, this is for mingw gcc from mingw.org.  For those who might not know, in the Windows Security dialog listing of threats, if you expand a thread, there's an Actions drop-down  which allows "restore" or "allow". To block Windows Defender from acting on a set of files: Windows Security >
Virus & threat protection >
Virus & threat protection settings >
Exclusions

Comment: ... and it looks like it's not just mingw gcc getting caught in this way:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1046937/windows-defender-reports-a-trojan-1.html